# Is it bad for the screen to keep turning on and off many times?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, screensaver

In screen timeout settings, windows 10 has option to turn off screen after desired minutes..

1. Is bad for screen if I set to turn off screen after 5min, so screen  keep turning on and off
   during my work day many times? Is better to use screensaver instead?

(Goal is to extend screen lifetime.)

Comment: i doubt that the screen actually turns off ... it is probably displaying  a black image

Comment: No. The display monitor is not subjected to complete power cycling, which can be detrimental. The host OS is merely disabling the visibility of the display, e.g. turning off the backlight, or enabling a low-power sleep mode.

Comment: @jsotola If screen only display black image then  this is  bad for pixels burn?

Comment: @sawdust What is better for avoid  pixel burn and increase screen lifetime, screensaver or set screen turn off from windows 10 settings? Why is this "turn off" mode determinal?

Comment: AFAIK an LCD display could not have "*pixel burn*"; that would be an issue with a display technology where the pixel is actively emitting light, e.g. CRT, plasma, and OLED. For the screen lifetime of the typical LCD with LED backlighting, the difference between screensaver versus screen off is probably not significant. The real goal is typically to save on power consumption. Turning the screen back on takes longer than replacing the screensaver with the normal desktop image.

Comment: @sawdust There is a myth out there that LCD displays do not suffer from burn in. This myth is false. I have personally witnessed LCD displays suffer from burn in on multiple occasions.

Comment: @user707264 - Perhaps, but Wikipedia mentions that it is not a permanent condition.

Comment: Black screen = no pixel emissions = less power and less usage of the pixels = less wear on the pixels. Screensaver = pixels working = more wear.

Comment: @jsotola I want to address this specifically because it derailed the entire discussion. [DPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling) is used to signal the screen to go to a low-power mode. And the display will do that. Both the panel and the backlight will _fully turn off_. Even CRTs supported that.

Comment: @harrymc that only really applies to active emission screens such as OLED. Black screen vs white screen is the same power for an LCD monitor as the backlight is on in either case

Comment: @Mokubai So do I need  use screensaver or turn off from windows 10 settings, to increase lifetime and avoid burn? IPS LCD

Comment: @user707264 let your computer turn it off. Screensavers were only really useful when CRTs took ages to warm up and had their own annoyances. Nowadays there will be a tiny amount of stress on the PSU in the monitor as it wakes up which is going to be largely offset by the reduced stress while it is asleep and mostly turned off. Only use the screensaver if you absolutely cannot tolerate the 1-2 seconds it takes your monitor to wake up.

Comment: Tempest in a teapot.  I have yet to wear out or damage a screen. Any computer- laptop or external screen.  Any electronic device.  The oldest working CRT I have is 45 years old and the screen is in perfect condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What’s most stressful for almost any electronics device (that doesn’t have mechanical components) is being on. When the display is in sleep mode both panel and backlight (if applicable) are off. This is exactly what you want.

Power cycling low-power electronics without also power cycling their power supply has a negligible impact on lifetime. While the display is sleeping, its power supply is still connected to mains.

---

On older flat panel displays with cold cathode fluorescent backlight, power cycling could have more of a negative effect, because CCFLs require a high-voltage inverter that is more prone to failure.

Nowadays, all flat panel displays that do have a backlight use LEDs for that.

Comment: "What’s most stressful for almost any electronics device (that doesn’t have mechanical components) is being on"  So your advice is set in settings screen turn off after minimum minutes?

Comment: @user707264 You yourself must pick a timeout value that is suitable for your work. Having the screen turn off after 1 minute while you are reading a text would hardly be ideal.

Comment: No doubt things may have changed over the years, but the exact opposite advice used to be true. Back in the 80s when I worked in multi-million-dollar recording studios, nothing was ever switched off [and damn the cost]. All the main equipment was left on 24/7/365. The only things with off switches were the lights;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following excerpt will help, from the article
[Are Screensavers Still Relevant? When to Use Them (And When Not To)](https://www.makeuseof.com/oled-vs-lcd/).

> While the logic of screensavers is solid, it's only relevant today if
> you still use CRT monitors or plasma screens. [LCD and LED monitors
> don't have image burn problems like they
> do](https://www.makeuseof.com/oled-vs-lcd/), and since laptops and
> monitors are now primarily LCD or LED, the purpose of the screensaver
> is moot.
>
> Note that even on LCD and LED monitors, displaying the same image for
> many days or weeks can cause "stuck pixels", but that's a temporary
> issue. You can actually fix stuck pixels with software, whereas CRT
> image burn is a permanent problem.
>
> Some people believe that screensavers exist to save power, but that's
> entirely false. Computers actually use more power when running a
> screensaver in order to keep the screen on. Want to save power? Ditch
> screensavers completely. All modern operating systems have
> power-saving features that turn the screen off when inactive.

Final word : It's better for the screen and the computer's
hardware to  turn off the screen, rather than to use a screensaver.
A screensaver exercises the CPU and GPU and wastes power,
which is also a factor that needs to be taken in account.

Comment: " It's better for the screen and the computer's hardware to turn off the screen" turn off manualy with power button or with windows settings?

Comment: Windows settings is enough. Powering down the monitor once a day will not have a noticeable effect on its lifetime. It might effect the lifetime of the power-button if done frequently. A monitor will draw very minimal power as long as it's not turned off.